# Android handling HTTP response

Tags: android, http, request, okhttp

I've just started writing my first Android app and I face a problem. I don't know how to correctly handle a HTTP response. I've found way to create a GET request (with okhttp) and found the way, to handle response with Callable. I'm getting array of my objects, and then need to create new adapter for RecycleView (with this array), but I can't set the adapter from the main thread. I don't know how to get Data from that Callable.

Making request

```
 public static void getDonerPoints() {
    try {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://192.168.2.64:9000/donerPoint/get?count=100&orderBy=rating&orderDirection=asc")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(
                new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        Log.d("mLog", "request error");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        try {
                            final ArrayList<DonerPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
                            if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
                                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                                    points.add(mapper.readValue(jsonArray.getString(i), DonerPoint.class));

                                ListFragment.setNewContentForAdapter(points);
                                Log.d("mLog", "ok");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception exc) {
                            Log.d("mLog", exc.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });

    } catch (Exception exc) {
    }
}
```

Setting Adapter

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_tab, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    return rootView;
}

public static void setNewContentForAdapter(List<DonerPoint> points){
    mAdapter=new PointAdapter(points);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

And Excexption

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Maybe i need to do it not in static context?

Comment: Please post some code to illustrate what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Write single class like below,

Class MyTask{

//create interface for callback

// write code for remote operation

// once remote operation done give callback to your binding activity

// don't forget to unbind your activity from this class as it will lead to memory leak as well when your activity will be in on stop stage it will crash as you will not allowed to update UI after on stop callback so remove this call back on stop.

}

Answer (score 0):

just like this , u will find it worked

```
public static void getDonerPoints() {
    try {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://192.168.2.64:9000/donerPoint/get?count=100&orderBy=rating&orderDirection=asc")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(
                new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        Log.d("mLog", "request error");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        try {
                             new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                              public void run() {
                                final ArrayList<DonerPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
                                if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
                                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                                    points.add(mapper.readValue(jsonArray.getString(i), DonerPoint.class));

                                ListFragment.setNewContentForAdapter(points);
                                Log.d("mLog", "ok");
                            }
                        }
                });
                        } catch (Exception exc) {
                            Log.d("mLog", exc.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });

    } catch (Exception exc) {
    }
}
```